# Racket: `remove` element from list on a text file

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

**Problem Description:**

I am encountering a problem trying to remove my item from my list.
The list was previously written to a text file using `call-with-output-file` and is now being read using `call-with-input-file`.
After reading, the list looks like this: `("a" "b" "c")`.
The element should be removed with `remove`.

**Code:**

Read/Write:

```lisp
(define lst
    (call-with-input-file "todo.txt"
      (lambda (des)
        (read des))))

(call-with-output-file "todo.txt" #:exists 'update
       (lambda (out)
         (write lst out)))
```

Removal:

```lisp
[(equal? action "remove todo")
     (display (~a "Choose an ToDo to remove:\n" lst "\n"))
     (remove (string-trim (read-line)) lst)
     (call-with-output-file "todo.txt" #:exists 'update
       (lambda (out)
         (write lst out)))
     (display "Removed.")]))
```

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the program to write the new list in my text file.

**Actual Behavior:**

My program overwrites the file with the same list as before (no deletion, no error).

*Thanks for any help!
-Till*

Comment: `remove` returns a *new* list that is ignored because you don't capture it in a variable or anything.

Comment: Lisp works with lists the way most programming languages with with numbers. If you have a variable `A` and you want to remove `3` from its value, you can write `A - 3` in many conventional languages, or `(- A 3)` in a Lisp. But you understand that this doesn't change `A`; it uses `A` as an input, calculates a new value and returns it. The `remove` function is the same, but for lists.